# Building an iPhone app that fires a repeated Local Notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm building a small, simple application for iPhone (I'm not that experienced). All it has to do is display a link to a website on it (yes really, thats it). But i need a local notification to fire every week at the same time to alert the user to click the link in the app. Now because I'm not very experienced, i don't really know where to start. I have googled around and found how to repeat a local notification: http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/04/13/local-notifications-in-iphone/. But i dont even know where to put this code?? Do i create a view based application, if so what method do I put the above code in. If someone could give me an outline of what I could do or even just give me some things to google (keywords etc) and I can go off and read up on it. This app is being built out of necessity, not so much my own learning, so I just need to get it done! Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use this to schedule a notification:

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    //setting the fire dat of the local notification. Put the date you want the notification to be sent
    localNotification.fireDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease]; 

    //setting the time zone
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    //setting the message to display
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Notification Body";

    //default notification sound
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


    localNotification.alertAction = @"Action!";

    //Saving regionIndex and searchIndex
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value", @"key", nil];
    localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
    [userInfo release];

    //schedule a notification at its specified time with the help of the app delegate
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];    
    [localNotification release];
```

Then, every time the user loads the app, you can use scheduledLocalNotifications to check if the notification for this next week was already scheduled.

```
    NSArray *notifications = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]];
    for (UILocalNotification *notification in notifications) {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSdate *date = notification.fireDate;

        // Here is where you can check if the notification was already scheduled    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A single view template would probably be the best to start with.  Local notifications are pretty easy to work with, first place to start is to understand how they work and how they should be used.  The scenario you have laid out sounds right for a local notification.  Start by looking at [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).  There are lots of examples of how this is done.